# JSON is no defined

Tags: javascript, json

in the json.js file i am getting an error on 199th line

`199: JSON = JSON || {};` error is, JSON is not defined

Why is this happining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, reading the value of an undefined variable throws a *ReferenceError* (see [GetValue(V) in ECMAScript](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.7.1)). So you should use `typeof` before accessing it:

```
JSON = typeof JSON !== "undefined" ? JSON : {};
```